# Heroku: restful_authentication logins are now case sensitive? How can I change that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, restful-authentication

I recently moved a Rails app from Slicehost to Heroku.

The app uses restful_authentication.

Now, on Heroku, usernames are case-sensitive on login.

So say someone has a username of "JoeSchmoe". On Slicehost (using MySQL) they could login with "joeschmoe" or "Joeschmoe" but on Heroku (which uses PostgreSQL) unless they type in their username with the correct capitalization, they get an error saying the username couldn't be found.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres comparisons are case-sensitive by default, so you'll need to update your generated `User.authenticate` method to comply with that - without knowing exactly what version of restful_auth you're using (or the options you installed it with), it's hard to provide the exact code, but you'll want the comparison to look something like this:

```
def self.authenticate(login, password)
  return nil if login.blank? || password.blank?
  u = find :first, :conditions => ['lower(login) = ? AND activated_at IS NOT NULL', login.downcase] # need to get the salt
  u && u.authenticated?(password) ? u : nil
end
```

That should work in MySQL, as well - `lower()` is a synonym for `lcase()`, at least in 5+